# Angular CORS requests fail to Laravel backend, but preflight look good

Tags: angularjs, ajax, laravel

In short, I'm posting data with Angular to a Laravel backend. The OPTIONS/preflight request looks good, but the subsequent POST fails saying that Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing from the requested resource.

I'm using Laravel 5 with Angular 1.2.26. Some further documentation on the backend middleware can be found here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-cors-headers-with-filters.

Laravel middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , 'http://laravel.app:8001')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With')
            ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '28800');
    }
```

Angular config - I've tried with various combinations of the commented code, same results each time:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    //$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    //delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
    //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
    //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```

Preflight/OPTIONS:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Request URL:http://laravel.app:8000/api/v1/authentication/login
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:laravel.app:8000
Origin:http://laravel.app:8001
Referer:http://laravel.app:8001/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://laravel.app:8001
Access-Control-Max-Age:28800
Allow:GET,HEAD,POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 24 Nov 2014 16:01:57 GMT
Server:nginx/1.6.2
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=blahblah; expires=Mon, 24-Nov-2014 18:01:57 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=blahblah; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:02:00 GMT; Max-Age=-1416844797; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

POST:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
Request URL:http://laravel.app:8000/api/v1/authentication/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:47
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:laravel.app:8000
Origin:http://laravel.app:8001
Referer:http://laravel.app:8001/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.65 Safari/537.36

Request Payload
{email: "x", password: "x", rememberMe: false}
email: "x"
password: "x"
rememberMe: false

Response Headers
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 24 Nov 2014 16:01:57 GMT
Server:nginx/1.6.2
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Comment: what do the server logs say?

Comment: Server logs don't have anything. I did just change the method to GET and it works, so it seems to be POST requests that fail.

Comment: Odd indeed, it seems that your server is not receiving the request correctly... do try to print out the contents on the request on the server side to see what's in it.

Comment: Interesting, so with further debugging, the POST never hits that middleware. GET requests hit it and I can dump the headers.

Comment: Well, now you just need to debug / trace till you find the issue

Answer (score 3):

After stepping through the VerifyCsrfToken middleware I've established that it was indeed a token mismatch.

The reason is that Angular was not supplying the CSRF token via header or via a parameter in the post. It worked for GET and OPTIONS requests because these do not validate against the token.

So, I looked into Angular and there is documentation on XSRF Protection (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and lots of discussion out there on how to add the appropriate headers (e.g. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5122#issuecomment-36157820).

I haven't had a chance to follow any of this up as I have to keep my project moving and my particular use case allows me to get away with disabling VerifyCsrfToken as I only need CORS whilst in development.

But hopefully this will give someone else a starting point for solving this issue more fully.

Comment: Ok, after more research, this is what I have determined.

If you want to use CSRF protection, it should work out of the box with Laravel 5 and Angular because the cookie and header that Laravel uses are the ones that Angular expects (as described in https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection).

However, if you want to use CORS then you cannot because the Angular doc says that **the CSRF header is specifically disabled for cross-origin requests**.

The recommended approach seems to be to use your own API key system and disable CSRF

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure if this is an issue with Laravel and the VerifyCsrfToken middleware or not, but the root cause of my issue was that the CSRF token validation was failing. When the error was thrown, the new headers were not included. I'm unclear on the order that these middlewares run in, perhaps that's it, but nonetheless, once I removed the VerifyCsrfToken from the middleware stack, everything lit up.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but disabling the VerifyCsrfToken middleware isn't fixing it

Comment: Correction! It does work. I had forgotten that I had changed the routing to GET during earlier tests. Once everything was set back to POST, disabling VerifyCsrfToken got everything working again

Answer (score 0):

I had seme problem. If you use middleware to set Headers, but create a new Response, `Response::json()`, `Response::make()`, etc. on controller, this new object don't get the headers set by middleware.

Comment: Hi @Rafael, I saw this comment somewhere else in SO. I'm modificating the request from a Middleware, and it passes this request through the stack when I tested it with POSTMAN. However when the request is from angular, the request propagates without change.   

I could see that when Content-Type: application/json, the request remains immutable, wheter cors is needed or not.  Could you please explain better your comment, and how can I solve it.  For now I'm using the Facade Request (which in fact has the modifications when in the controller, contrary to the FormRequest object injected.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
In CORS middleware
Add the following header.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //All the domains you want to whitelist
    $trusted_domains = ["http://localhost:4200", "http://127.0.0.1:4200", "http://localhost:3000", "http://127.0.0.1:3000"];
    if (isset($request->server()['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        $origin = $request->server()['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

        if (in_array($origin, $trusted_domains)) {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Auth-Token,x-xsrf-token');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```